# How to automatically cluster a U-Matrix?

Tags: clustering, image-processing, self-organizing-maps

After training a self-organising map, one can calculate the [U-Matrix](https://users.ics.aalto.fi/jhollmen/dippa/node24.html). There are [some tools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Umatrix/Umatrix.pdf) to manually visualize it and identify clusters, but I'm wondering if there is any algorithm to do this process in an automatic way (i.e. not having a human looking at the figure to identify the clusters).

Is there any way to do this? I'm writing my code in R. I haven't found anything of the kind on the Internet, so maybe someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, I've seen clustering algorithms being run on a SOM's U-Matrix. It isn't much common however because SOMs are used to *visualize* high-dimensional data on 2 dimensions.

An example you can look at [this](https://somoclu.readthedocs.io/en/stable/example.html#initialization-with-principal-component-analysis-and-clustering-the-results), where a DBSCAN is run on a U-matrix to cluster its neurons. This example is from the Python library 'somoclu'. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any packages on R.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was actually looking for some algorithm regarding image segmentation using the U Matriz, and not the nodes of the map themselves.